Hold to sprint in Unreal Engine 5
I am trying to make this sprinting function in UE5. Surprisingly, I haven't seen many questions on this, but the enhanced input made this harder for me.
My main problem is the input and getting it to change from sprinting while being held to walking when released.
Blueprint I did
I tried setting the function as shown above, but I wasn't really sure what I was doing. A previous version of mine stopped the sprinting, but only for a second and then it started sprinting again while I wasn't holding down the key.

You can use the branch function to do that as part of the blueprint. The logic would be: Key (your move key) -> branch -> condition (which key you are using to convert to sprint) -> NOT-> true node -> walk program|| false node -> sprint program.
